# How to display content of an xml file to specific windows form controls on a form and allow navigation?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-forms-designer

I have an XML file which is loaded into an XMLDocument object. The XML file has many < tour > nodes. I want to display the contents of a < tour > node on a Windows form with the ablity to navigate through < tour > nodes with a navigation control. How can I do this?

I want the form in which the information is displayed on to look similar to:

[image: form]

Below is a sample of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<tours>
   <tour>
      <description>
      <![CDATA[
<p><i>Travel Scotland!</i> goes south to England blah blah...</p>
  ]]>
  </description>
  <tour_name>The Lake District</tour_name>
  <tour_photo>Lake.jpg</tour_photo>
  <tour_guide>Mary Taylor</tour_guide>
  <td_email>mailto:mtaylor@tscotland.com</td_email>
  <tour_start>6/15/2003</tour_start>
  <tour_end>6/19/2003</tour_end>
  <itinerary>
     <day>
        <day_number>1</day_number>
        <plan>London arrival</plan>
     </day>
     <day>
        <day_number>2</day_number>
        <plan>Train to Windemere</plan>
     </day>
     <day>
        <day_number>3</day_number>
        <plan>Second day in Windemere</plan>
     </day>
     <day>
        <day_number>4</day_number>
        <plan>Trip to Ambleside</plan>
     </day>
     <day>
        <day_number>5</day_number>
        <plan>Hiking tour to Grasmere</plan>
     </day>
  </itinerary>   
</tour>
<tour> ANOTHER TOUR ETC.
```

Comment: What is the problem, what have you tried?

Comment: You say what you want but don't say where you got stuck while doing it.

Comment: Well what would be the best way of displaying and navigating through < tour >s on the form? I have tried creating a DataSet to hold the information but I'm not sure if this is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifics about the XMLDocument object, but in pseudo-code terms you need to do this:

Iterate through your `<tour>` nodes, and load the information into an array of a custom-defined structure. e.g.

```
    struct tour{
        String description;
        String tourname;
        String tourimagelink;
        ...
    }
```

Then you need to iterate through each element of your array, creating Windows Form controls (preferably within a docked panel or such, so you can scroll) for each entry. For your y-axis offsets, you will need to figure out the height of the information block. If using a for loop to iterate through the elements, a formula like this might help:

```
    y = (i*blockHeight) + offsetOfControl;
```

I hope this helps in some regard.

EDIT: Better yet - instead of using a struct, you could use a class which exposes all the Windows Form controls so that you can attach them to the main form.